# How to set a field in Java to 0 if the argument is negative?

Tags: java

I keep getting this error message,

The following code was executed:

```
 LemonadeStand ls = new LemonadeStand();
 ls.setLemons(1);
 ls.setLemons(-1);
```

ls.getLemons() should have returned 0, but it returned -1.
Make sure setLemons sets the field to 0 if the argument is negative.

And I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong in my code, which is shown below. Thanks.

```
public void setLemons(int newLemons)
{
    if(lemons < 0)
    {
        lemons = 0; 
    }
    lemons = newLemons;
}
```

Comment: You left out the error message

Comment: `if(lemons < 0)` should be `if(newLemons < 0)`

Comment: @JimGarrison He also needs either an `else` clause, or he needs to return after setting `lemons` to zero. Otherwise, the value will be overwritten once the code in the `if` is executed.

Comment: Why are we voting to close this question? The OP asked a question that was clear, and provided minimal, reproducible code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK Saul,

```
public void setLemons(int newLemons)
{
    if(newLemons < 0)
    {
        lemons = 0;

    } else {
        lemons = newLemons;
    }
}
```

Now,

```
LemonadeStand ls = new LemonadeStand();
ls.setLemons(1); // sets value to 1
ls.setLemons(-1); // sets value to 0;
```

Comment: More concisely, `lemons = Math.max(newLemons, 0)`

Comment: @accessviolation this is most likely a homework and probably can't use library functions.

Comment: @accessviolation Thanks for mentioning the alternative that some programmers prefer. For my part I find the version in the answer easier to read. Also when it’s a few lines longer, it’s still concise. And it’s closer to the version in the question, which may be easier for the OP to grasp.